# javascript private members in prototype

Tags: javascript, private-members

I would like to start that I'm not feeling comfortable with JS.

I've experienced a problem with implementing private methods in prototype. Let's say we have a Person class. I want to expose greet method but keep getName private.

```
function Person(name) {
    this.name = name;
}

Person.prototype = (function() {

    function getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    function greet() {
        console.log("hello " + getName());
    }

    return {
        greet: greet
    }
})();

p = new Person('Szymon');
p.greet();
```

above code won't work as getName doesn't have context ("this" points to window where name doesn't exist).

My solution to this problem was:

```
function greet() {
    console.log("hello " + getName.call(this));
}
```

however it's get a little bit messy with bigger class.

Is this a clean solution? I would be grateful for any feedback.

Comment: I think the best solution is to not worry about private and public, just prefix internal methods with an underscore.

Comment: @Teemu: This convention is widely accepted, and does not really lack competence. Of course you'd need some competence to decide when an application of this convention is feasible.

Comment: @kit: Notice that the terminology "private members in prototype" might be confusing. `getName` is *not* a member (property), it's just a local variable.

Comment: @Bergi I agree, I would name it private method.

Comment: @elclanrs for me this convention sucks as private property/method could be overwritten.

Comment: @kit, or use `Object.defineProperty` to make it non-writable.

Comment: @kit: No, that's just what I mean: it's not a *method*, as it is not a property of the instance it's called upon. And btw, you should not care about "overwritability", as basically everything can be overwritten in JS.

Comment: @Bergi I don't think that getName from example above could be overwritten

Comment: @kit: Yes, `getName` cannot. But why would anyone care who wants to alter the behaviour of your class? They'd just overwrite `greet` or simply set a different `.name`.

Answer (score 0):

The way you've written it `getName` is not a method, but a static function. If you don't want to make it a public method (I don't see a good reason why a getter would be private), and don't want to use `.call()`, then you will need to pass the instance explicitly:

```
Person.prototype = (function() {

    function getName(self) {
        return self.name;
    }

    function greet() {
        console.log("hello " + getName(this));
    }

    return {
        constructor: Person,
        greet: greet
    }
})();
```

I'd consider all three solutions equally clean.

Comment: "I don't see a good reason why a getter would be private" it's just an example. JS is not my world but neither solution seems clean to me.

Comment: Well, "clean" JS just has everything as properties and does not use any privacy at all. As privacy would be hard to defend in a language as dynamic as JS anyway.